# ReferenceError: module is not defined (angular js unit testing with Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I found a lot of questions about this, but the answers didn't work for me.

I have a small controller in angular js. It works fine, and I wanted to start testing.

I downloaded Jasmine standalone from [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases). I put my controller in the "src" folder, and another js file in "specs", following the instructions provided [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing). Then I edited the SpecRunner.html including my files. It didn't work.

After looking for solutions for the "module is not defined" error, I included the angular-mocs.js reference in the html and in the karma.conf.js file, making sure that is was **before** the tests. It still doesn't work.

Anyone knows what can be wrong?

Comment: Add your karma.conf , jasmine test case and other related files to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I still had to use `npm install angular`. Stupid me...